# How do I get my JQuery form submit to work along a page update function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, thymeleaf

I have two functions on my Thymeleaf page, the first one handles a form submission with an ajax POST request:

```
$(".[form-class-name]").submit(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     ...

     $.ajax({
          type: "post",
          url: [post-url]
     });
});
```

The second one updates the page's body at a regular interval:

```
function update() {
$.ajax({
     type: "get",
     url: [updateUrl],

     success: function (data) {
          /*<![CDATA[*/
          $("body").html(data);
          /*]]>*/
     }
});

     setTimeout(update, 3000);
}
```

Both of these functions work separately, but once I include both of them in my script, only the update is working. The form submission script never executes, and since `preventDefault()` is never called, form submission causes the page to reload.

Is there a way that I can get these functions to cooperate?

EDIT: Including the entire script combined -

```
$(function () {
     $(".[form-class-name]").submit(function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();

          $.ajax({
               type: "post",
               url: [post-url]
           });
       });

       function update() {
           $.ajax({
               type: "get",
               url: [updateUrl],

               success: function (data) {
                   /*<![CDATA[*/
                   $("body").html(data);
                   /*]]>*/
               }
           });

           setTimeout(update, 3000);
       }

       update();
});
```

Comment: can you share the code after you merge both of them.

Comment: @HamzaArshad - included in my most recent edit

Comment: It is working at my end, can you please create a small working demo which should replicate your issue.